# Ensure data "exists". React, or Endpoint?

Tags: javascript, rest, undefined, reactjs, single-page-application

I have a moreso best practices question regarding Flux/React for a SPA that gets most of it's data from REST endpoints.

In a React components Render function, when I do something like:

```
<MyComponent data={this.state.data} />
```

then in the component, I use {this.props.data}, whether for drawing a graph, text, whatever, it obviously causes problems if data is undefined or occasionally, 0.

Assuming this data lives in the store and is fetched aysnc (and thus also won't exist as soon as the app is loaded), where does it make the most sense to "check" or "ensure" data is defined and is a value that won't break child components? Should I init the data structure in the store will all null/empty values, or make my endpoints return the entire data structure in a similar fashion? Or, does it make sense to do data validation in the actual component and litter it with:

```
if (!(typeof(this.props.data) === "undefined")) {
     Render Component as normal
    } else {
             Return null or an empty div or whatever
    }
```

I feel like there should be a basic solution to this problem, but I feel like I'm constantly chasing down little things breaking on the off chance undefined/null/0 values "get through", for example drawing a D3 donut chart and every value in the array is 0.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you most comfortable with? I think there are definitely multiple ways that are all acceptable to do this and is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Checking in the component is fine as well.